# Column chart in Google Chart displays bar below min

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

Ok, I've been looking for something similar to what I'm experiencing online but I can't so I decided to ask around here for some advise to solve my issue.

I'm using Angular Google chart and trying to create a column chart to display historical values for portfolio totals.

**Code to create chart**

```js
           $scope.createPortfolioBalanceChart = function(){
                var data = JSON.parse($scope.portfolioChartData.rows.toJSON());
                console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.portfolioChartData).replace(/\\/g,''));
                var minValue = _.reduce(data.rows, function(memo, bal){ 
                    var value = bal.c[1].v;
                    return (value !== null && value < memo) ? value : memo;
                }, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
                var maxValue = _.reduce(data.rows, function(memo, bal){ 
                    var value = bal.c[1].v;
                    return value > memo ? value : memo;
                }, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);

                var rangeBleed = (maxValue - minValue) * PortfolioBalanceChartConfig.rangeBleedPadding;

                var chart = {};
                chart.type = 'ColumnChart';
                chart.data = data;
                chart.options = {
                    'height': 300,
                    'fill': 20,
                    isStacked: false,
                    'vAxis':{
                        'baselineColor': 'none',
                        'gridlineColor': 'none',
                        'format': '$#,###',
                        'position': 'right',
                        'viewWindow' : {
                            'min': rangeBleed > 0 ? minValue - rangeBleed : 0, // if the range is 0 then start the graph from 0
                            'max': maxValue + rangeBleed
                        }
                    },
                    'displayExactValues': true,
                    'tooltip' : {
                        'trigger': true
                    },
                    'legend': { 
                        'position': 'none' 
                    },
                    'bar': {
                        'groupWidth': 30
                    },
                    'colors': ['#33b4e6', '#0675c2'],
                };

                chart.formatters = {
                    number : [{
                        columnNum: 1,
                        pattern: '$ #,##0.00'
                    },
                    {
                        columnNum: 2,
                        pattern: '$ #,##0.00'
                    }]
                };

                $scope.portfolioBalanceChart = chart;

            };
```

Note:
minValue and maxValue above was calculated to add padding to the chart data.

**$scope.portfolioChartData**

```js
{
  "rows": {
    "cols": [
      {
        "label": "Period",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "label": "Balance",
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "role": "style",
        "type": "string",
        "p": {
          "role": "style"
        }
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Mar 2015"
          },
          {
            "v": 68484.43
          },
          {
            "v": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Apr 2015"
          },
          {
            "v": 68484.43
          },
          {
            "v": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "May 2015"
          },
          {
            "v": 68484.43
          },
          {
            "v": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Jun 2015"
          },
          {
            "v": 68484.43
          },
          {
            "v": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Jul 2015"
          },
          {
            "v": 68484.43
          },
          {
            "v": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Today"
          },
          {
            "v": 600000
          },
          {
            "v": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "cols": [
    {
      "label": "axis",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "label": "Portfolio",
      "type": "number"
    }
  ]
}
```

stackoverflow is preventing me to post image so here's a sample image of the chart constructed above:

http://postimg.org/image/gtnq81au3/

Comment: Do you have a question to ask, or a problem with the above code you need help with?

Comment: hey, I have some problem with the code above. If you can see the screenshot I posted in the link, the bar is overlapping the label in the x axis.. pretty weird.

Comment: Can it be fixed with css?

Comment: Possibly take a look at this also; http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved the issue at last. There seems to be some property hiding in the google chart docs that enables you to set what should be the baseline. This is different from what the viewWindow.min is. I added it below the viewWindow property.

```js
            $scope.createPortfolioBalanceChart = function(){
                var data = JSON.parse($scope.portfolioChartData.rows.toJSON());
                var minValue = _.reduce(data.rows, function(memo, bal){ 
                    var value = bal.c[1].v;
                    return (value !== null && value < memo) ? value : memo;
                }, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
                var maxValue = _.reduce(data.rows, function(memo, bal){ 
                    var value = bal.c[1].v;
                    return value > memo ? value : memo;
                }, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);

                var rangeBleed = (maxValue - minValue) * PortfolioBalanceChartConfig.rangeBleedPadding;

                var chart = {};
                chart.type = 'ColumnChart';
                chart.data = data;
                chart.options = {
                    'height': 300,
                    'fill': 20,
                    isStacked: false,
                    'vAxis':{
                        'baselineColor': 'none',
                        'gridlineColor': 'none',
                        'format': '$#,###',
                        'position': 'right',
                        'viewWindow' : {
                            'min': rangeBleed > 0 ? minValue - rangeBleed : 0, // if the range is 0 then start the graph from 0
                            'max': maxValue + rangeBleed
                        },
                        'baseline': rangeBleed > 0 ? minValue - rangeBleed : 0 // set to be the same as min to prevent bar overlapping label below it
                    },
                    'displayExactValues': true,
                    'tooltip' : {
                        'trigger': true
                    },
                    'legend': { 
                        'position': 'none' 
                    },
                    'bar': {
                        'groupWidth': 30
                    },
                    'colors': ['#33b4e6', '#0675c2'],
                };

                chart.formatters = {
                    number : [{
                        columnNum: 1,
                        pattern: '$ #,##0.00'
                    },
                    {
                        columnNum: 2,
                        pattern: '$ #,##0.00'
                    }]
                };

                $scope.portfolioBalanceChart = chart;

            };
```